# Authentication headers in REST API call

Tags: java, web-services, rest

In my java webapplication  i have added a webservice call @ URL `10.10.10.21:8088/openbravo/com.data.service.`

When i hit the URL from browser, it asks me for a Username and password. After entering those details, i can see the json output (desired output).

The web service provides a JSON REST service. I want to implement a basic client UI to fetch this JSON data and publish on the page. As a part of client i have written basic html code with jQuery ajax to make call to this URL. But i get 401 unauthorized response.

```
$("input#add-contact").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://10.10.10.21:8088/openbravo/com.indavest.openbravo.restaurantpos.service",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
            });
        });
```

How can i add the authentication headers to the call. Is the above lines of code the right approach to make call to the rest webservice. I am new to the Webservices concepts. Any help would be great!!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for basic authentication:

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "http://localhost:8080/myservice/function?format=json",
headers: { "Authorization" : makeBasicAuth("1", "1") },
data: jsonText,
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function( data, statusTxt, xjobj )
    {
        showSuccess( data, statusTxt, xjobj, "blabla" );
    },
            error: function( xjobj, statusTxt, errorThrown )
            {
        showError( statusTxt, xjobj, errorThrown, "blabla" );
        }
    });
```

with:

```
function makeBasicAuth(user, password)
{
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;
}
```

but this is for basic, there is also digest authentication (I recommend you wikipedia for a great explanation of those http technics) and so son, but the idea is similar.

Comment: Thanks! for the response..   in the code - data:  jsonText ..   what is jsonText  here?

Comment: @SangramAnand This is the payload, the HTTP body.

Comment: I tried with the above piece of code,  its reaching the server, but the Authorization header is going null. Am i missing any params here ?

Comment: the authorization header is null? this is strange, have you checked it with fiddler?